# Should we have a tag for the set theory NFU?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I'm wondering if we should have a tag for the set theory [NFU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations). On the one hand, I personally would like to see the tag stick around, since I think NFU is a very interesting and potentially useful set theory. On the other hand, as far as I can tell, only three questions have ever been asked about NFU (counting one I asked today).

Comment: I've added a link to the New Foundations Wikipedia site. You might want to add some description to this question of exactly what NFU is.

Comment: I noticed earlier that the other two `nfu` questions were recently edited, with the only change the addition of the `nfu` tag.  I _just_ noticed that _you_ were the one making these edits.  Upon further inspection, it seems that the `nfu` tag was created at about the same time as the aforementioned edits.  Did _you_ happen to create this tag?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I did.

Comment: I will add link to a recent question about related (but broader) tag: [Tag for alternative set theories?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28258).

Answer (score 7):

I don't think three questions is worth having a tag for. I even doubt a `new-foundations` tag would be viable.

If we are to do something in this area. I would prefer to have an `axiomatic-set-theory` which wouldn't be as likely to attract elementary questions from askers who don't really care about axiom systems as the current `set-theory`. (They are supposed to go in `elementary-set-theory`, even relatively advanced ones about ordinals -- but elementary-foo tags are a blight in general; they are hard to discover for the users who need them most).

Tags are fairly cheap, but not free -- at a minimum unused tags have the downside of showing up when the system suggests tags for new question, creating confusion for new users who have to guess at which tags are *actually* appropriate for their new questions.

Comment: Yes, I like this solution. (Should I accept it? I feel like it's not my place to say that it's the *correct* solution.) Should we rename `nfu` to `axiomatic-set-theory`, then?

Comment: I think "nfu" is fine, it may be even better to call it "new-foundations", though it brings a slight risk of wrongly tagged questions. But "axiomatic-set-theory" is definitely the wrong tag (By default, this refers to ZFC, its fragments, variants, and extensions).

Comment: I'm curious how you see these three set-theory tags interacting.  I have a feeling that `set-theory` and `axiomatic-set-theory` would have a negligible symmetric difference.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: There would still only be two tags. I'm imagining moving the current "set-theory" to "axiomatic-set-theory" and then perhaps "elementary-set-theory" to "set-theory".

Comment: I would actually leave the tags as set-theory and elementary-set-theory, if this is the road we are heading. Some questions on "axiomatic-..." would be elementary, some would be advanced, and the useful distinction we currently have would be lost.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a problem with the (brand-new) `nfu` tag, *per se*, but my preference would be a catch-all (or at least catch-a-little-bit-more) `new-foundations` tag.  This would add perhaps two or three questions to the tag.